# Is this normal? CPU usage 50% for ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, cpu-usage

Running on Macbook Pro unibody OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard, dual-core. I notice Activity Monitor is stating the ruby process running at 50% consistently...

Is anyone seeing the same results? Is this 'normal'?

**EDIT:**
Further into clarifying. My hands are not on the keyboard. The Rails server and ruby console are running, but without any activity. I am also running Rails 3.1 RC1.

Comment: Ehrm, surely it would depend on the code that is being run, no? Or are you saying rails uses 50% CPU while idle?

Comment: Is there a possibility that it is being attacked from outside?

Comment: No, everything is on our local environment. In a private LAN

Comment: Does this happen immediately when you start the server, without making any request to it?

Comment: It happens every so often, and stays at 50% consistently. Seems to have gone away. For the time being. See my response in the Answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've restarted the server. The CPU process for Ruby seems to have subsided to a more reasonable state / percentage. At the moment, at a 0.2.

I'm starting to suspect that something may have triggered a CPU spike with Rails 3.1 RC1. After all, it is still not the stable release of Rails. Will observe how this plays out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing. If you do simply nothing, then no, this isn't normal. If you are actively developing, then you might have created an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one infinity loop uses one core of CPU (50% usage in your case, because your Mac has got dual-core).

Comment: That's not the way Activity monitor reports CPU usage -- 50% means 50% of a single core, not 50% of the total cores on the computer.  On a 12-core Mac, full utilization is 1200%.

Answer (score 0):

It's not common, no.  I've seen it happen a few times, but I don't know why.. It's not a endless loop in my code.   I suspect a race condition somewhere deep in the stack or in the interpreter.   It happens most often after a resume from sleep event I think.

I just kill the process.